# Show customer spend per day and whether they have spent the previous day (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I  am trying to create a new row for each customer who spends per day, and a column that indicates whether they spent money the day before or not. If a customer spends twice a day, they'd still only have 1 row in the table. If the customer spent money the previous day, then it would show up as TRUE.

This is the original table below:

```
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| datetime            | customer_id | amount          |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2018-03-01 03:00:00 | 3786        | 14.00000        |
| 2018-03-02 17:00:00 | 5678        | 25.00000        |
| 2018-07-09 18:00:00 | 5647        | 1000.99000      |
| 2018-08-17 19:00:00 | 5267        | 45.00000        |
| 2018-08-25 08:00:00 | 3456        | 78.00000        |
| 2018-08-25 17:00:00 | 3456        | 25.00000        |
| 2018-08-26 03:00:00 | 3456        | 34.90000        |
| 2019-02-03 08:00:00 | 3468        | 0.00000         |
| 2019-03-09 06:00:00 | 1111        | 100.00000       |
| 2019-05-25 14:00:00 | 3456        | 15.00000        |
| 2019-07-02 14:00:00 | 88889       | 45.00000        |
| 2019-07-04 03:00:00 | 8979        | 9.00000         |
| 2019-07-09 14:00:00 | 4567        | 9.99000         |
| 2019-08-25 08:00:00 | 1234        | 88.00000        |
| 2019-08-30 09:31:00 | 1234        | 30.00000        |
| 2019-08-30 12:00:00 | 9876        | 55.00000        |
| 2019-09-01 13:00:00 | 88889       | 23.00000        |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

This is the CREATE statement:

```css
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spend` ( `datetime` datetime NOT NULL, `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `amount` decimal(10, 5) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`datetime`)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-03-01 03:00:00', 3786, 14.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-03-02 17:00:00', 5678, 25.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-07-09 18:00:00', 5647, 1000.99000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-08-17 19:00:00', 5267, 45.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-08-25 08:00:00', 3456, 78.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-08-25 17:00:00', 3456, 25.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-08-26 03:00:00', 3456, 34.90000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-02-03 08:00:00', 3468, 0.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-03-09 06:00:00', 1111, 100.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-05-25 14:00:00', 3456, 15.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-07-02 14:00:00', 88889, 45.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-07-04 03:00:00', 8979, 9.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-07-09 14:00:00', 4567, 9.99000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-08-25 08:00:00', 1234, 88.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-08-30 09:31:00', 1234, 30.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-08-30 12:00:00', 9876, 55.00000);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-09-01 13:00:00', 88889, 23.00000);
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```css
SELECT CAST(datetime AS DATE) AS day, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS daily_spend,
FROM spend
WHERE amount is not NULL
ORDER BY date;
```

This code is not working at the moment, but I'm trying to fix it as best I can.

I've had a look through some of the posts, but the closest I could find was this: [count transaction per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46314038/count-transaction-per-day-for-each-customer)

I'm trying to produce a table that looks like this:

```
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| day        | customer_id | spent_previous_day |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2018-03-01 | 3786        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2018-03-02 | 5678        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2018-07-09 | 5647        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2018-08-17 | 5267        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2018-08-25 | 3456        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2018-08-26 | 3456        | TRUE               |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-02-03 | 3468        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-03-09 | 1111        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-05-25 | 3456        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-07-02 | 88889       | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-07-04 | 8979        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-07-09 | 4567        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-08-25 | 1234        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-08-30 | 1234        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-08-30 | 9876        | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-09-01 | 88889       | FALSE              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

**Edit:**
This is the current code I'm using, based on the advice I've received.

```css
select customer_id, CAST(datetime AS DATE) AS day,
      max(date(datetime))  over (partition by customer_id 
                          order by CAST(datetime AS DATE)
                          range between interval 1 day preceding and interval 1 day preceding
                         ) is not null AS spent_previous_day
from spend
```

This is the resulting table:

```
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| day        | customer_id | spent_previous_day |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-03-09 | 1111        | 0                  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-08-25 | 1234        | 0                  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-08-30 | 1234        | 0                  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2018-08-25 | 3456        | 0                  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2018-08-25 | 3456        | 0                  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2018-08-26 | 3456        | 1                  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-05-25 | 3456        | 0                  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2019-02-03 | 3468        | 0                  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

I've tried to do a `GROUP BY day, customer_id`, but it comes up as an error.

Comment: Hint : `lag()` window analytic function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that customers do not make multiple purchases on the same day, just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       ( date(lag(datetime) over (partition by customer_id order by datetime)) = date(datetime) - interval 1 day
       ) as prev_day_flag
from spend t;
```

If you can have duplicates, then try this instead of `lag()`:

```
max(date(datetime)) over (partition by customer_id
                          order by date(datetime) 
                          range between interval 1 day preceding and interval 1 day preceding
                         ) is not null
```

EDIT:

If you want one row per customer per day:

```
select s.*,
       ( date(lag(dte) over (partition by customer_id order by dte)) = dte - interval 1 day
       ) as prev_day_flag
from (select customer_id, date(datetime) as dte, sum(amount) as amount
      from spend s
      group by customer_id, date(datetime)
     ) s;
```

Comment: Why between use `interval 1 day` on both sides?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Only the previous day is needed and that is a handy way to define it.  This will work with multiple records on the same day for the same customer.

Comment: I've tried both suggestions and they both work partly work. However, I'm still struggling with resolving the issue of duplicate daily spends.

Comment: Do a `group by day, customer_id` that way you only have one record by day and can use the first query.

Comment: @ToniIdowu . . . That depends on what you want.  If you want one row per customer per day, then follow Juan's advice and aggregate the data at that level.  Your question suggests that you want all the rows in the original data.

Comment: I only want one row per customer per day. I've followed Juan's advice and done a group by day. However, it comes up as an error.

Comment: Thanks. The proposed edit works. The pre_day_flag column results in a few nulls. Anyway I can fix this? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @ToniIdowu . . . The `NULL`s are where there is no previous day.  That seems like a reasonable value for that situation.